# Выборка всех названий коммитов в репозитории.C#

Tags: c#, git, repository

Добрый день.
Хочу вывести все названия коммитов определёного репозитория в консоль.
Получаеться только вывести последнее название коммита.
Вывожу удалённо. Нет смысла клонировать их локально.
Использую библиотеку **LibGit2Sharp**.
Мой метод, который выводит удаленно последний коммит:

```
    public string GetHash(string url)
    {
        string s = Convert.ToString(url);
        var refer = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(s).FirstOrDefault() as SymbolicReference;
        return refer.Target.TargetIdentifier;
    }
```

Comment: Для того, что бы получить "названия коммитов" (я так понимаю, commit messages), Вам как минимум придется выкачать себе половину репозитория. Либо ручками реализовать "dump http protocol" и зная последний коммит в ветке, получить "commit object", распарсить его, вытянуть сообщение и родительский коммит(ы). И повторять эту процедуру до получения желаемой глубины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой код возвратит первый элемент последовательности, которую возвращает метод `ListRemoteReferences`:

```
var refer = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(s).FirstOrDefault() as SymbolicReference;
```

Попробуйте так:

```
var refer = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(s);

foreach(var refen in refer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(refen.Target.TargetIdentifier);
}
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я в этом еще не особо понимаю.

Comment: Но есть ошивка Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LibGit2Sharp.Reference>'

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans, обновил ответ, попробуй по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans если все работает ставьте зеленую галочку и upvote.